# is linfu 2.3 released anywhere?

Tags: linfu

i see projects and articles that reference linfu.core version 2.3 but when i go [to the linfu website here](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/downloads/list), i only see version 2.2.

does anyone know where to download linfu.core version 2.3 ??

Comment: for the person who downvoted, can you please explain why you did that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: http://github.com/philiplaureano/LinFu/archives/master

The googlecode site for LinFu is deprecated and LinFu is now hosted on Github.